# Is it possible to have an application using python 2 and python 3 modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, compatibility, python-2.x

I'm currently building an application in my Raspberry Pi. This application have to use I2C bus along serial port. Previously I developed both applications independent between them; for I2C app, I used a python3 module for handling the bus. But for handling serial port I use a python 2 module.

Now I want to build an app that handle the two interfaces. Is this possible? How should I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

Comment: well, you can convert python2 to 3 or 3 to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used 2to3 to convert python 2 modules. But due to the module interacts with serial port (pyserial), byte handling were not full correctly converted, so I have to edit the code after conversion using encode/decode functions.

Answer (score 0):

Search for backports or try to split it up into different processes.